# end code execution after redirecting to another page without using response.end, ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect to another page and then stop the rest of the code from execution, without using response.end as it raises exception to end 
example:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, false);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    //here I want to stop code execution but without using return as well as this code will be placed in a method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.Transfer("url", true);
```

that is another way to redirect URL, 
hopefully it can help you
PS: this is server side code

Answer (score 0):

Per [`Response.Redirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method; the last parameter is `bool endResponse` which states that *Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate.* So change it to

```
Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will also throw ThreadAbortException in order to end response, I want to end the response without throwing the exception

Comment: @GTarek, in such case consider using `Server.Transfer()`. You shouldn't use `Response.Redirect()` with your requirement.